# path treated differently between app.use() and app.get()

Tags: node.js, express

How come when I do a GET request on `/foo`, my request passes through the first middleware function in example A, but bypasses it in example B ?

Example A

GET '/foo"

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
     console.log("req passes through here");
     next();
}

app.get('/foo', function(req, res, next) {
     console.log("then req passes through here");
}
```

Example B

GET '/foo"

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     console.log("this part is bypassed...");
     next();
}

app.get('/foo', function(req, res, next) {
     console.log("then req passes through here");
}
```

[app.use()](http://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#app.use) and [app.get()](http://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#app.get) use the same path argument.

So how come the middleware mounted on `/` in not executed in example B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.use()` instructs the app to use the specified path for all methods (GET, PUT, POST, etc) on all calls.  Specifically `app.use`:

> Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified path: the middleware function is executed when the base of the requested path matches path.

While `app.get()` instructs it to use the path for that specific method (GET) for that specific path only.

> Routes HTTP GET requests to the specified path with the specified callback functions.